# Звук в анимации Android

Tags: аудио, android, анимация

Пытаюсь добавить звук в анимацию, то есть что бы имеющийся звуковой файл циклически воспроизводился при повторении анимации. В итоге получилось что звук воспроизводится всего раз и при том не тогда когда нужно (не в начале анимации). Вот код

```
anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.jumper);

anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.ping);
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mp.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mp.stop();
    }
});
```

Comment: попробуйте проигрывать звук в отдельном потоке

Comment: Как это можно сделать?